# Multiply by different factor depending on weekday or weekend

Tags: python-2.7

```
from datetime import datetime, time

datetime.now()

if 0 <= now.weekday() <= 4:
    cap = (((ConstantSeries(value=2574)) ))*(ConstantSeries(value=0.64))
else:
    cap = (((ConstantSeries(value=2574)) ))*(ConstantSeries(value=0.46))

capacity = cap
```

The constant series works well and is not the issue. I want to be able to multiply the time series by a different factor depending on whether it is a weekday or not

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the weekday falls in the range of weekdays:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

today = datetime.now()

if today.isweekday() in range(0, 5):
    cap = (((ConstantSeries(value=2574)) ))*(ConstantSeries(value=0.64))
else:
    cap = (((ConstantSeries(value=2574)) ))*(ConstantSeries(value=0.46))

capacity = cap
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but this doesn't seem to work. I get:AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'isweekday'

Comment: It might be work stating that the ConstantSeries is a panda series which matches the value with a time series. so for example date/time1 = 2574, date/time2 = 2574 etc